# flash.keep not working until subsequent page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I wrote a redirect so it checks if the page is https:// and if it is it directs it to http://.

However, I want to use a flash message that was passed from the https:// but it disappears during the redirect so it never shows up for the user. So, i tried `flash[:notice].keep` but that doesn't work either. the redirect happens, nothing appears, but then on the next page it finally shows the message. here's my code:

```
  def turn_off_https
    if (request.ssl? && params[:controller] != 'subscriptions')
      flash[:notice].keep
      redirect_to :subdomain => "www", :protocol => "http://"
    end
  end
```

basically i only have 1 page of my site that i want to have https:// but after adding it, any other page the user goes to has https:// even though I dont want that. That is why I added this before_filter to the application controller to make sure to switch back to http. how do I make sure the notice gets shown upon redirect?

I also tried adding ":notice" to the redirect_to in that method but that just put the message in the URL as a param and didn't actually load it on the page

Comment: Is the session being lost in its entirety because the domain is different?

Comment: yes, probably. however, I have the flash notice when i'm about to make the redirect...so shouldn't i just be able to add it to the redirect_to ?

Comment: It's still stored in the session - if the session is being preserved it won't work

Comment: so is there a better implementation of what i'm trying to do? i need to go from https://secure.website.com to http://www.website.com and maintain the notice

Comment: You need to configure the session domain to cover both those 2 domains

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-keep):

```
flash.keep            # keeps the entire flash
flash.keep(:notice)   # keeps only the "notice" entry, the rest of the flash is discarded
```